# Inserir imagem no ListView via JSON + SQL

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

Eu criei um código que trás perfeitamente os resultados via JSON do meu banco de dados e preenche a minha ListView com Strings, mas eu gostaria que o banco trouxesse da coluna "imagem" que eu criei, o endereço relativo a imagem (Ex: http://localhost/dashboard/Android/Imagem/car.jpeg) e a ListView carregasse esta imagem dentro dela através do endereço gravado no banco de dados, os endereços das imagens ficam gravados na coluna "imagem" no meu banco de dados, já tentei de várias formas, mas não consegui, vou postar o código que preenche a minha ListView somente com strings, pois este código está funcionando corretamente:

```
private void showEmployee(){
```

JSONObject jsonObject = null;

ArrayList> list = new ArrayList>();

try {
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(JSON_STRING);
        JSONArray result = jsonObject.getJSONArray(Config.TAG_JSON_ARRAY);

`for(int i = 0; i<result.length(); i++){ 
        JSONObject jo = result.getJSONObject(i);

        String id = jo.getString(Config.TAG_ID);
        String name = jo.getString(Config.TAG_NAME);
        String salary = jo.getString(Config.TAG_SAL);
        String image = jo.getString(Config.TAG_IMAGE);

        HashMap<String, String> employees = new HashMap<>();
        employees.put(Config.TAG_ID,id);
        employees.put(Config.TAG_NAME,name);
        employees.put(Config.TAG_SAL,salary);
        employees.put(Config.TAG_IMAGE,image);

        list.add(employees); 
    }

  } catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  } 

  //ListAdapter
  SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
        ViewAllEmployee.this,
        list,
        R.layout.list_item,
        new String[]{Config.TAG_ID,Config.TAG_NAME, Config.TAG_SAL, Config.TAG_IMAGE}, 
        new int[]{R.id.id, R.id.name, R.id.salary, R.id.image}
   );

   listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}`

Comment: Você fez um adaptador customizado para essa exibição ?

Comment: Eu tentei, tentei até por diretamente o endereço das imagens do drawable para ver se a imagem aparecia, mas nada...

Comment: Você precisa fazer uma requisição para buscar essa imagem e depois atribuir ela como recurso do ImageView, existem duas bibliotecas que podem te ajudar muito com isso : [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) e [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide)

Answer (score 1):

Bom, como não foi especificado eu recomendaria que você fizesse isso utilizando alguma das ferramentas já existentes (O Glide inclusive é mantido pelo Google)

Para utilizar o Glide é necessário que você adicione a dependência dele.

No arquivo buid.gradle do seu **APP** (Existe um na raiz do projeto, adicione no do APP). Localize a parte de `dependencies` e adicione essa linha:

```
dependencies {
  compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.1.0' // <---- Não precisa, mas é recomendado utilizar uma RecyclerView ao invés da ListView
}
```

Dentro do seu adaptador, no método `getView` você faz algo como :

```
  @Override 
  public View getView(int position, View recycled, ViewGroup container) {
  final ImageView minhaImageView;
  if (recycled == null) {
    minhaImageView= (ImageView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.minha_image_view, container, false);
  } else {
    minhaImageView= (ImageView) recycled;
  }

  String url = minhaListaDeUrls.get(position);

  Glide
    .with(meuContexto)  // <------ É necessário passar um contexto para ele, pode ser seu Fragment ou um Context
    .load(url)   // <--- Sua Url
    .centerCrop()  // <---- Estético, é o método como a imagem será posicionada na view
    .placeholder(R.drawable.loading_spinner)  // <---- Você pode especificar um Drawable para aparecer enquanto carrega
    .crossFade()    // <----- Animaçãozinha :)
    .into(minhaImageView);   // <----- Onde a imagem será carregada.

  return minhaImageView;
}
```

Note que implementei uma lista só com a ImageView apenas para efeito de entendimento, o importante é a parte `Glide....` o resto é só pra você definir em qual ImageView você vai carregar a imagem, adapte à sua necessidade